# Prevent duplicates in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

### My desired behavior is..

1. to see if there is a match (a user_id you like, also likes you)
2. sort by the latest time (closest date/time to now) activity to create a match i.e., if I liked you after you already liked me, then I'm the latest person involved and my timestamp should show.
3. If there is a matches_appointment_time.proposed_time, then show those rows first by order of closest date/time to now. The highest rows should also have agreed flag set as 1

### Here is my table structure for three tables:

#### likes

```
id(pk) | user_id | liked_user_id | timestamp
```

#### info

```
id(pk) | user_id | name | age | gender | timestamp
```

#### matches_appointment_times

```
id(pk) | user_id_1 | user_id_2 | proposed_time | agreed | timestamp
```

### Here is an example of duplicate row behavior:

[image]

### Here is a link with SQL to replicate my three tables

http://rextester.com/DFUI4453

### Here is my query:

```
SELECT
  info.user_id,
  info.name,
  info.age,
  info.gender,
  DATE_FORMAT(likes.time, '%c/%e/%y') AS matchedTime,
  t.proposed_time AS proposedTime,
  t.agreed
FROM info
INNER JOIN likes
  ON info.user_id = likes.liked_user_id
  AND likes.user_id = ?
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
  user_id_1,
  user_id_2,
    MAX(agreed) AS agreed,
  MAX(DATE_FORMAT(proposed_time, '%b %d, %Y @ %h:%i %p')) AS proposed_time
FROM matches_appointment_times
WHERE proposed_time > NOW()
GROUP BY user_id_1,
         user_id_2) t
  ON (info.user_id = t.user_id_1 OR info.user_id = t.user_id_2)
  AND (t.user_id_1 = ? OR t.user_id_2 = ?)
WHERE likes.liked_user_id IN (SELECT
  user_id
FROM likes
WHERE likes.liked_user_id = ?)
ORDER BY 
CASE
  WHEN t.proposed_time IS NOT NULL AND t.agreed = 1 THEN t.proposed_time
END DESC,
CASE
  WHEN t.proposed_time IS NOT NULL AND t.agreed = 0 THEN t.proposed_time
END DESC,
CASE
  WHEN t.proposed_time IS NULL THEN likes.time
END DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
Please use Distinct in Subquery:


SELECT  
  info.user_id,
  info.name,
  info.age,
  info.gender,
  DATE_FORMAT(likes.time, '%c/%e/%y') AS matchedTime,
  t.proposed_time AS proposedTime,
  t.agreed
FROM info
INNER JOIN likes
  ON info.user_id = likes.liked_user_id
  AND likes.user_id = ?
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
Distinct
  user_id_1,
  user_id_2,
  MAX(agreed) AS agreed,
  MAX(DATE_FORMAT(proposed_time, '%b %d, %Y @ %h:%i %p')) AS proposed_time
FROM matches_appointment_times
WHERE proposed_time > NOW()
GROUP BY user_id_1,
         user_id_2) t
  ON (info.user_id = t.user_id_1 OR info.user_id = t.user_id_2)
  AND (t.user_id_1 = ? OR t.user_id_2 = ?)
WHERE likes.liked_user_id IN (SELECT
  user_id
FROM likes
WHERE likes.liked_user_id = ?)
ORDER BY 
CASE
  WHEN t.proposed_time IS NOT NULL AND t.agreed = 1 THEN t.proposed_time
END DESC,
CASE
  WHEN t.proposed_time IS NOT NULL AND t.agreed = 0 THEN t.proposed_time
END DESC,
CASE
  WHEN t.proposed_time IS NULL THEN likes.time
END DESC
```

Comment: Still getting duplicates with this

Comment: can you provide sample (some rows ) data in all tables. will resolved your issue

Comment: Here's a link with some dummy values I generated http://rextester.com/DFUI4453. Let me know if you need anything else